# building portfolio having only deals from my works.

Tags: portfolio

I want to work as freelancer. In order to do this, IT IS useful to have PROFESSIONAL portfolio.

Here is my situation:

I am doing professional programming since 10 years.

Before this i was programming too.

THE BIG PROBLEM building portfolio is that i don't have too many evidence of my work. I don't have 99% of my apps/websites.

I have fortunately couple of screenshots of some websites/apps. 
The problem is that i wasn't doing archives of things. For example, during classes i did puzzle game and music editor. Later i bought new computer or disc broke - there were no backups.

Another example - i did research and research work for big corporation. I get grade "passed" about this work - it was half year working. I get note to my index and that's all. With other even more curious projects, that i could show now - i don't have nor source code nor compiled apps. There is one screenshot of headline in newspaper and my picture that i am the author, but that's all...

Yes, it's sad, currently if i realised that a few people will choose me because they actually WANT to see jobs.

Later, i was working for around 10 companies in average half year on various terms.

I sent to all companies letter in which i am pleasing to send some confirmation of my works. Only one company sent me this. It seems that i  have bad relations with these companies. I had terms that my work belongs to company. I made an iOS app - i don't know even in which name is published. I made an Android game - the same, don't know name and don't have source code. Even don't have iphone to create a new one app. Company gives hardware, then company takes. It's so sad now, because i did it all and i have experience, but people want to see working software, which belongs to company and they made my long nose. Another project i was working for 9 months as Architect and programmer. Actually boss said that he thanks me ( i was probably too expensive ) and in one day they disconnected me from repository, nor i can't show project to noone, because they sell it somewhere which is top secret. The same with other projects.

Now, here is my question.

How can i build my portfolio. Do i have to drive personally to each company and beg them to give my example of my work?All i have is couple screenshots, knowledge about project in my mind and for all projects i have papers with deals - terms and agreement. 
Can i scan these deals and show on portfolio - it's all evidence i have?
Is scanning deals and publishing to internet legal? I have two shelves of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About building a portfolio, you can see other topics here. Many of us described the way to build a portfolio. Let's not repeat that.

And about the lack of the real samples that clients can see: do not be worried about it too much. The most important is how you write a proposal when bidding for some project and if a client can see your expertise in the proposal.

If you do these 2 things with quality of 10-year-programmer guy, then the client will not ask for anything more.

So if I were you, I would attach screenshots of the projects I worked on, as many as I have, and put my effort to make quality proposals.